# Python: Classes that Depend on Each Other

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

I'm trying to create a set of classes where each class has a corresponding "array" version of the class.  However, I need both classes to be aware of each other.  Here is a working example to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.  But this requires duplicating a "to_array" in each class.  In my actual example, there are other more complicated methods that would need to be duplicated even though the only difference is "BaseArray", "PointArray", or "LineArray".  The BaseArray class would similarly have methods that only differ by "BaseObj", "PointObj", or "LineObj".

```
# ------------------
# Base object types
# ------------------
class BaseObj(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    def to_array(self):
        return BaseArray([self])

class Point(BaseObj):
    def to_array(self):
        return PointArray([self])

class Line(BaseObj):
    def to_array(self):
        return LineArray([self])

# ------------------
# Array object types
# ------------------
class BaseArray(object):
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = [BaseObj(i) for i in items]

class PointArray(BaseArray):
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = [Point(i) for i in items]

class LineArray(BaseArray):
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = [Line(i) for i in items]

# ------------------
# Testing....
# ------------------

p = Point([1])
print(p)
pa = p.to_array()
print(pa)
print(pa.items)
```

Here is my attempt, which understandably raises an error.  I know why I get a NameError and thus I understand why this doesn't work.  I'm showing this to make clear what I'd like to do.

```
# ------------------
# Base object types
# ------------------
class BaseObj(object):
    ArrayClass = BaseArray
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    def to_array(self):
        # By using the "ArrayClass" class attribute here, I can have a single
        # "to_array" function on this base class without needing to
        # re-implement this function on each subclass
        return self.ArrayClass([self])
    # In the actual application, there would be other BaseObj methods that
    # would use self.ArrayClass to avoid code duplication

class Point(BaseObj):
    ArrayClass = PointArray

class Line(BaseObj):
    ArrayClass = LineArray

# ------------------
# Array object types
# ------------------
class BaseArray(object):
    BaseType = BaseObj
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = [self.BaseType(i) for i in items]
    # In the actual application, there would be other BaseArray methods that
    # would use self.BaseType to avoid code duplication

class PointArray(BaseArray):
    BaseType = Point

class LineArray(BaseArray):
    BaseType = Line

# ------------------
# Testing....
# ------------------

p = Point([1])
print(p)
pa = p.to_array()
print(pa)
print(pa.items)
```

One potential solution would be to just define "ArrayClass" as None for all of the classes, and then after the "array" versions are defined you could monkey patch the original classes like this:

```
BaseObj.ArrayClass = BaseArray
Point.ArrayClass = PointArray
Line.ArrayClass = LineArray
```

This works, but it feels a bit unnatural and I suspect there is a better way to achieve this.  In case it matters, my use case will ultimate be a plugin to a program that (sadly) still uses Python 2.7, so I need a solution that uses Python 2.7.  Ideally the same solution can work in 2.7 and 3+ though.

Comment: That isn't really monkey patching, that's just a normal way of assigning attributes to classes.

Comment: Are your different subclasses of `BaseArray` actually doing different aside from that attribute? Because then it makes more sense to me to define some generic container, like `BaseArray` (array isn't a great name, but whatever) let's just call it `class Array(object)`, and then in `Array.__init__` you provide the type of the base object, so for example, `point_array = Array(Point, items)`. IOW, why inheritance instead of composition?

Comment: Then in `BaseObject`, you can defined `to_array` for all subclasses simply ass `return Array(type(self), [self])`. In general, I am highly suspect of needless type hierarchies. Python is a duck-typed languae, and even if you use annotation and a third-party static type checker, you could make `Array` generic.

Comment: It feels unnatural to assign the class attributes that way though because then the class isn't fully defined until some place later in the file.  The class isn't really complete until that assignment occurs, which may also be easy to forget doing if new types are added.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.  The actual use cases does need the "array" types to be unique to each type of object it contains and they have a number of methods that are applicable only to those types themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using decorators.  I prefer this to the class attribute assignment ("monkey patch" as I called it) since it keeps things a little more self consistent and clear.  I'm happy enough with this, but still interested in other ideas...

```
# ------------------
# Base object types
# ------------------
class BaseObj(object):
    ArrayClass = None
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    def to_array(self):
        # By using the "ArrayClass" class attribute here, I can have a single
        # "to_array" function on this base class without needing to
        # re-implement this function on each subclass
        return self.ArrayClass([self])
    # In the actual application, there would be other BaseObj methods that
    # would use self.ArrayClass to avoid code duplication

    @classmethod
    def register_array(cls):
        def decorator(subclass):
          cls.ArrayClass = subclass
          subclass.BaseType = cls
          return subclass
        return decorator

class Point(BaseObj):
    pass

class Line(BaseObj):
    pass

# ------------------
# Array object types
# ------------------
class BaseArray(object):
    BaseType = None
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = [self.BaseType(i) for i in items]
    # In the actual application, there would be other BaseArray methods that
    # would use self.BaseType to avoid code duplication

@Point.register_array()
class PointArray(BaseArray):
    pass

@Line.register_array()
class LineArray(BaseArray):
    pass

# ------------------
# Testing....
# ------------------

p = Point([1])
print(p)
pa = p.to_array()
print(pa)
print(pa.items)
```